# Recommended font for math symbols?

Tags: fonts, units

I need to show unit symbols of micro, nano, kilo, mega ..
Is there a recommend front for this usage?

ex: 10µ Ω

Comment: No one uses the units package anymore?

Comment: I am developing a scientific app!

Comment: @ManuelKuehner why should I use the units package over siunitx? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: @Argo: The package is much simpler and stable. I experienced that I used siunitx and then I updated my LaTeX installation a couple of months later and I had an error due to changed in the code of siunitx. Of course siunitx is more powerful. But in normal day to day work units is good enough and I don't need to remember many commands. And I love the nicefrac option. All of that is highly subjective!

Comment: I see, I'll look into it. I had to typeset some imperial units for an exam in physics and that was kinda a pain to do manually properly.

Comment: Use \usepackage{units} and the for example \unit[180]{cm} and \unitfrac[47]{kg}{m} or \unitfrac[26]{kg}{m$^2$}.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [siunitx package](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx), it's pretty much the best way to typeset (SI)units, since you don't have to take care of spacing, symbols and whatnot.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document
This is an example of the siunitx package: \SI{10}{\micro\ohm}
\end{document
```

Gives the following:

[image]

Comment: Also the `\num` command by itself is very useful: it inserts thin spaces between triplets of digits in five-digit or higher numbers. So, `\num{10000}` would output `10 000` (with a thin space).

Comment: @WChargin agreed, although I don't use it for the space between digits, but rather for scientific notation. ``\num{8,85e-12}`` is faster than ``$8,85\cdot 10^{-12}$`` (and it probably handles the spacing as well).

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}

$10\,\upmu\Omega$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Have a look at package `siunitx`. It makes life easier for writing values and units.